# Regular Expressions "7+(4x+2)(3*5)^5" -> "7+(#+#)(3*5)^5"

Tags: regex

I am new to regular expressions and need some help.

How can I turn

string : `7+(4x+2)(3*5)^5` 
into : `7+(#+#)(3*5)^5`

using regular expressions. Is it possible?

basically replace 0-9a-z of string with ( opening 0-9a-z + 0-9a-z ) closing

***EDIT***

other examples:

string : `3(3+5)^4+8(0+2)` 
into : `3(#+#)^4+8(#+#)`

string : `(4+6)` 
into : `(#+#)`

string : `(4+6)(4+6)` 
into : `(#+#)(#+#)`

Comment: Is the regex only applicable to this specific case?

Comment: PHP, C, or C# isn't the syntax the same?

Comment: "Works for me": `s/\Q7+(4x+2)(3*5)^5/7+(#+#)(3*5)^5/`

Comment: Why doesn't "7+(4x+2)(3*5)^5" -> "7+(#+#)(#*#)^5"? Regular expressions need to be very exactly defined, I *suspect* the question is: "how can I replace all occurrences of '(number+number)' with '(#+#)'?" While regular expressions can work here -- at least in this specific case -- if anything more complex is required looking to a simple parser might be a good decision..

Comment: @PatrickLorio Then update the post more :) Also include the language/environment the regular expression will be used in, and any current code, if applicable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
(?<=\()\d+[a-z]?\+\d+[a-z]?(?=\))
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2v5dg)

These two `(?<=\()` and `(?=\))` is a look behind and a look ahead, they ensure, that there is a bracket before and ahead.

`\d+[a-z]?` is at least one digit followed by one letter.

The `+` is a special character and needs to be escaped, so `\+`.

Replace this match with

```
#+#
```

Comment: @Patrick - What happens if there is a variable named `x2` or `yy99` or a floating point number ?

Comment: @sln I am trying to learn regular expressions and it was an example to get what I needed basically this syntax: "(?<=\()" and "(?=\))", but to answer your question this would work : "(?<=\()\d+[a-z]?\^?\d?\+\d+[a-z]?\^?\d?(?=\))" I just grew on stema's answer. Link : http://regexr.com?2v5dm

Comment: @Patrick - I guess it could be non-computational algebraic notation, but then yy is y*y and fails, but who knows. There are many modes for failure then.

Comment: @sln "non-computational" : It could be fixed by a recursive algorithm re-formatting the notation beforehand.

Comment: @Patrick - Well, language parses mathematical expreessions a little different then algebraic notation. Its not that easy. As for assertions and regex in general, the key to understanding them is to realize that you are a physical observer inside the expression, and that you exist *Between* characters. You can look ahead/behind without moving and you can advance or not. The regex is the abstraction that navigates the string. At all times though, your place is between characters, never on a character. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

untested: `s/(7\+\()4x\+2(\)\(3\*5\)\^5)/$1#+#$2/`

**edit** after your edit, (untested): `s/\([0-9a-z]+\+[0-9a-z]+\)/(#+#)/g`